# How do I configure a new Ubuntu installation to accept ws connections?

Tags: websocket

I just installed Ubuntu. How do I set it up to allow me to ws into it?

Right now I get "ws:// connect to host x.x.x.x port 8888 : no response". for example ws://172.23.45.100:8888 don't give any response and cannot open

output of `sudo iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I can ping the ip from another windows app  , but when telnet it fails to connect `telnet 172.123.45.100 8888`

also this is the output `sudo netstat -tnlp|grep 8888`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: outer computers will send and receive through this port

Comment: a streaming I install service that listen and handle all the requests

Comment: yes it run and listening

Comment: all I need is to open this port for  world

Comment: So you didn't just install Ubuntu, you have installed other software on it. Did you install ufw? Also, edit your post to include the output of `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 8888` and `ip a`

Comment: the output of the command "Can't open 8888 no such file or directory" also I didn't install ufw

Comment: sorry output is tcp6 0 0:::8888 :::* LISTEN @muru

Comment: is it important to install ufw

Comment: OK, please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: @muru kindly find updated question

Comment: So your service is listening on the correct port, you don't have any firewal rules blocking the port, so the last thing is: is the IP correct? Is the computer otherwise accessible from the other computers?

Comment: I can ping the ip from another windows app

Comment: but not on the port from windows telnet doesn't response @muru